# rpm: define my own variable in spec file

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Is there a way to declare my own variable inside of a `spec` file and refer to it as `%{my_var}` ?

Answer (score 3):

Define your variable at the beginning: `%define my_var my_value` and use it with `%{my_var}`.

According to [rpm packaging guide - defining your own macros](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/#defining-your-own), `%global` can be used too.

See also: https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/macros.html

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You use `%global` or `%define` for that. See for example the [fedora firefox.spec](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/firefox/blob/rawhide/f/firefox.spec).